Sharepoint overwrites material ui css
I am trying to use material ui for react my spfx solution. I can use the components but SharePoint overwrites some css for the material ui components. for example SharePoint makes the material ui selects arrow button wider (oval instead of circle). I can find the related classes and overwrite those classes in component with sx property but doing this kind of clearing is time consuming. is there any other way to use material ui in SharePoint with out this kind of css problems? Thanks a lot.
Example: I add the text field as an example down below. As you can see SharePoint online adds some css that brakes the style of the component. So I need to overwrite those SharePoint default css rules in material UI components with adding sx property to that component.


Edit: I add an example to clerify.

What SPFx component you are changing the styles? Webpart / Application Customizer? And in which file you are overwriting the styles? scss? or using your own stylesheet?

I am using it in webpart. basically I am not using any css but SharePoint's own css overwrites the material UI's css. like SharePoint gives all the input[type=text] a certain padding and this overwrites the material UI textfields padding and makes it smaller and uglier. to solve this I am adding padding to the text field via sx property

I add an example to show the problem better to the original post.
